# errno 10054 on Status check request

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

Ok, I've tried to resolve this with a couple of different libraries. I'm working on a script to look at thousands of sites and kick out specific items on the pages. I need to be able to reset the connection so that the script will continue without losing any data. I've tried catching the error and waiting but that doesn't seem to fix it as it eventually causes the script to error completely out. I get the error on the below snippet of code in my status check module.

```
def status(url): #checks the response code
 try:
     req=urllib2.urlopen(url)
     response=req.getcode()
     return response
 except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
     return e.code
     print e.code
 except urllib2.URLError, e:
     print e.args
     return e.args
```

But before trying this I used the below as instead of urrlib2

```
    parsedurl = urlparse(url)
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(parsedurl.netloc)
    conn.request('HEAD',parsedurl.path)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    return response.status
```